# Group isomorphism mapping generators to generators

Tags: group-theory

I know that an isomorphism between cyclic groups maps generators to generators, but is this still the case if the groups are non-cyclic?

Many thanks!

Comment: Yes; the property of being a set of generators is something that can be stated using the language of groups, so it's automatically invariant under isomorphism.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Suppose $G$ and $H$ are groups with $G=\langle a, b, c, \ldots\rangle$. Then every element $g\in G$ has the form $W(a, b, c, \ldots)$ (so is a word over the alphabet $a, b, c, \ldots$). If the map $\phi: G\rightarrow H$ is a homomorphism with the generators of $G$ mapped as follows $$\phi: a\mapsto x, b\mapsto y, c\mapsto z, \ldots$$ then we have the following. $$\phi(g)=\phi(W(a, b, c, \ldots))=W(\phi(a), \phi(b), \phi(c), \ldots)=W(x, y, z, \ldots)$$ Therefore, the image of the element $g$ is defined by the images of the generators.

Your task now is to work out where the fact that $\phi$ is a homomorphism was used. Note, however, that we *only* used the fact that $\phi$ was a homomorphism: the result holds for homomorphisms in general, and does not depend on the surjectivity or injectivity of the map.

Comment: Helpful. Though I have following doubt, W(x,y,z,......) is generator only for range-group of phi,right ? it will be generator for H only if phi is Surjective .Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @viru yes, you are correct (this is what the last sentence is saying).